# I lost my game after doing a hard reset of my playstation

Tags: ps4

I had to do a hard reset of my PS4 and lost all of my data on my PlayStation. I had had Call of Duty Advanced Warfare downloaded to the PlayStation and now I cannot find it. I purchased it through the PS4 online store and do not own a physical disk. I am wondering where I can find the game to redownload. Thanks so much! PS it does not appear in my library and I am very confused

Comment: Are you logged in to your PSN (aka SEN) account on your PS4?

Comment: Yeah im logged into my ps4 account. prior to the reset I had two users and I am currently logged into one of them. i dont know how to log into the other user.

Comment: If the game is not in the library under the "purchased" tab, then it can't have been bought with the account you are logged into. A reset of the console doesn't reset your purchases. Is it possible that you purchased the game with the other account? If the console was that account's primary PS4, then it would have shared the game for use by all other accounts.

Comment: If you think that you bought the game with your logged in account, you could also try to go to Settings -> Account Management -> Restore Licenses and see if it appears in your library then.

Comment: I only have one account I used to have two users under the account but when i logged back into the account the main one didnt show up. I have no idea how to add back to user. Thanks for the help also:)